# listdata.svc authentication issue

Tags: 2010, web-services, wcf

When I visit my local SP2010 instance on Windows 7 at localhost/_vti_bin/listdata.svc I get Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.  There's no details even though I've turned off Friendly errors in IE9 and have the web.config set as `<customErrors mode="Off" />.`

I attempted to create a Console application with VS2010 and add a service reference.  I get the following error:

> There was an error downloading 'localhost/_vti_bin/listdata.svc'. The
>   operation has timed out Metadata contains a reference that cannot be
>   resolved: 'http://localhost/_vti_bin/listdata.svc'. The HTTP request
>   is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

Note: a separate port 16xxx instance works fine.  It isn't working on port 80.

Comment: Did you setup the correct security in the client proxy?

Comment: I am very new to this, so No.  I am not sure where do this.

Comment: basically, you will have to update the app.config to to make the app match the server authentication requirement. Please update your question to show the content of the app.config. You can also read my [blog article](http://blog.hand-net.com/sharepoint/2010-04-14-sharepoint-2007-et-wcf.htm) that shows a WCF client configuration for SP 2007. This should be identical. It's in french, but I can past relevant portions in english when you'll have posted your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have just begun to create a console app.  No app config file exists I'm afraid.

Comment: if you created a service reference, you have an app.config. Otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Yes, instead of clicking Go, I just clicked OK and it generated this:  

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration><startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" sku="Client"/></startup>    </configuration>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to disable the Loopback check if you're running SharePoint locally (see here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)
2. Follow this for more detailed step by step how to configure http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/021babc6-2009-4ed9-81f4-ac48cc300c94?prof=required

Comment: Not having much luck mate.  I am able to view localhost:66XXX/_vti_bin/listdata.svc still, but can't hit the one on port 80.  The web.config to edit is: Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\web.config - right?

Comment: in your external application

Comment: This took a while and I kept coming back to it.  I did use the DisableLoopBackCheck Reg DWORD and it seems to have worked for me.  I only recently rebooted and everything works for this now.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope it helps
[Use PowerShell to allow Anonymous Access to GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandsilverlighttrainingcourse_anonymousaccesscsomsilverlightlab_topic5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many links on this and none of them helped. I was being blocked by a permission issue when accessing /_vti_bin/listdata.svc. I had to go into Component Service and give the NETWORK SERVICE Access permissions under the COM Security Tab. I also gave Launch Permissions to keep from messing around. This is on a DEV box. I will give this more attention when in Production.